# How to incress the session time mannually(without changing app.php) in cake php3

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to set the session time manually in the admin page. Like admin can set session time.i'm using Configure::write to overwrite the session which wrote in the app.php .but the value overwritten but the session not expired.
1st I tried to like this

```
Configure::write('Session', [
'defaults' => 'php',
'timeout' =>1 // 3 days
]);
$time= Configure::read('Session.timeout');
pj($time); // 1
```

but session not expiered.
next i tried like this.

```
  Configure::write('SessionTime', [
  'time' => '1'
  ]);
```

app.php

```
 `Session' => [
 'defaults' => 'php',
 'timeout'=>Configure::read('SessionTime.time')//in minutes
 ],`
```

i tried to sent the value to app.php but it not worked.
please any one help on this issue

Comment: This is not the correct approach, while each time Cake reads a session, it updates it with the current timestamp. But before doing it, it checks wheter it's valid or not by checking if  current timestamp is higher than (timestamp stored in session + `Configure::read('Session.timeout') * 60`) (valid) or not (invalid).

Comment: You can add something in session like the key `config.forceTimeout` and extend the cake session class to check if this key exists in session & use it to check if it's a valid session or not. Btw if you want to do this from your admin panel, you will have to read & write session of other ppl, you cannot do this except if you store sessions as files on server, for exemple in `TMP` directory, or in your database.

Comment: @Bobot  thanks for the comment .how to store the sessions as files on server could you please explain bit more about that.

Answer (score 1):

By setting timeout you can increase the session time manually in `core.php`

**Session.cookie** : The name of the cookie to use. Defaults to 'CAKEPHP'

**Session.timeout** : The number of minutes you want sessions to live for. This timeout is handled by CakePHP

**Session.cookieTimeout** : The number of minutes you want session cookies to live for

**Session.checkAgent** : Do you want the user agent to be checked when starting sessions? You might want to set the value to false, when dealing with older versions of IE, Chrome Frame or certain web-browsing devices and AJAX

**Session.defaults** : The default configuration set to use as a basis for your session.
 Four built in: php, cake, cache, database.
Take an example with description for each field

**Session.handler** : Can be used to enable a custom session handler.  Expects an array of of callables, that can be used with `session_save_handler`.  Using this option will automatically add session.save_handler to the ini array.core.php

**Session.autoRegenerate** : Enabling this setting, turns on automatic renewal of sessions, and sessionids that change frequently. See `CakeSession::$requestCountdown`.

**Session.ini** : An associative array of additional ini values to set.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => '', //Session type
    'timeout'  => '180',//Timeout in minutes
    'cookieTimeout' => '180', //Cookie Timeout in minutes
    'ini' => array('session.cookie_domain' => env('HTTP_BASE')),
    'handler' => array(
        'config' => '' // name
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment .if we can use the  config code in app controller for increase the session time.is those possible